# Gajim can't connect to gmail anymore

Tags: gajim

When I open Gajim and try to connect to my gmail account, it gives me the following:

1. Warns about an insecure connection:

   [image: Insecure connection: You are about to send your password on an unencrypted connection. Are you sure you want to do that?]
2. When I choose to connect insecurely, authentication fails, although my gmail username and password are correct:

   [image: Authentication failed with "gmail.com": Please check your login and password for correctness.]
3. Shows a "programming error" window:

   [image: A programming error has been detected: It is probably not your fault, but should be reported to the developers nonetheless.]

   The details are:

   > `Traceback (most recent call last):`
   >
   > `File "/usr/share/gajim/src/dialogs.py", line 1538, in on_response_ok`
   >
   > `self.user_response_ok(self.is_checked())`
   >
   > `File "gajim.py", line 2238, in on_ok`
   >
   > `gajim.connections[account].connection_accepted(data[0], 'plain')`
   >
   > `File "/usr/share/gajim/src/common/connection.py", line 739, in connection_accepted`
   >
   > `on_auth=self.__on_auth)`
   >
   > `File "/usr/share/gajim/src/common/xmpp/client_nb.py", line 445, in auth`
   >
   > `self._on_doc_attrs()`
   >
   > `File "/usr/share/gajim/src/common/xmpp/client_nb.py", line 470, in _on_doc_attrs`
   >
   > `if not self._sasl or self.SASL.startsasl == 'not-supported':`
   >
   > `AttributeError: NonBlockingClient instance has no attribute 'SASL'`

How can I fix this? I'm on Mandriva 2010.1

Answer (score 2):

This was just reported as a [bug](https://trac.gajim.org/ticket/7342) a few days ago. Apparently Google sends data differently from other servers, so they'll need to handle it specially, but it's not fixed yet.